# Create Static Header with Dynamic Empty Editable Rows in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Anyone have the idea how to create a dynamic row with header table in WPF program.
I am able to create the dynamic row with header, but unfortunately the rows unable to edit. (Attached Screenshot)

xaml (source code)

```
   <DataGrid Name = "dataGrid" CanUserAddRows="True" AutoGenerateColumns = "False" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2">

        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header = "NUMBER   " Binding = "{Binding Path=ID}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header = "STAGE ID  " Binding = "{Binding Path=StageID}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header = "STAGE DESCRIPTION   " Binding = "{Binding Path=StageDescription}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>

    </DataGrid>
```

cs (source code)

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= 4; ++i)
    {  
        dataGrid.Items.Add(new Stage());
    }

  public class Stage
  {
      public string ID { get; set; }
      public string StageID { get; set; }
      public string StageDescription { get; set; }
  }
```

Table

[image: screnshot table]

Answer (score 0):

```
private readonly ObservableCollection<Stage> stages
     = new ObservableCollection<Stage>();

 public СonstructorWindow()
 {
    InitializeComponent();
    dataGrid.ItemsSource = stages;
 }

 void SomeMethod()
 { 
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {  
       srages.Add(new Stage());
    }
 }
```